# List of headers to use Tensorflow C++ API using libtensorflow_cc.so

Tags: tensorflow

I want to know what all header files are required in order to use Tensorflow's C++ APIs. Like in case of C APIs, there is just a single header c_api.h which has all the functions, etc. declared, is there any such single header for C++ APIs? I tried searching this, but unable to understand what is required and what is not.

There is a huge list of headers in tensorflow/cc, tensorflow/core and tensorflow/c which are used to build libtensorflow_cc.so and we also ship most of these in the tensorflow's distribution (By TF's distribution I mean TF which is built using `bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`). Is that list of headers sufficient in order to use C++ API? or do we need to build any additional target in tensorflow/BUILD?

I've also gone through https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/ but can't really make out the exact list of required headers.

In one of the related posts, I found that tensorflow/bazel-genfiles contain the required headers. Please confirm this.

Thanks in advance,
Nishidha

Comment: Can you just pick the ones you need or include all headers?

Comment: The problem is how to find out what all headers are needed in order to use C++ APIs. My approach is I'm going through API doc and finding out which header defines a particular API/class/type and then if that header is included or not. While doing this, I found that some of header files like math_ops.h, array_ops.h, etc. are generated as part of some target and landed into bazel-genfiles directory. Could anyone please let me know how can I include content of bazel-genfiles directory into the distribution either by modifying any BUILD file or some other means?

Comment: I found that even some external dependencies' content like jemalloc headers viz. jemalloc*.h which is generated in bazel-genfiles are put into the distribution. Those are also created through cc_library and genrule combination. Similar thing is done for even cc_ops library that uses headers like array_ops.h, maths_op.h, etc. But unfortunately these headers are not making into the tensorflow's pip package. Could anyone please help me to get this specific case worked? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are building TensorFlow v2 C++ for Windows using bazel, kindly use

```
bazel build --config=opt tensorflow:install_headers
```

This will generate an `include` folder with the cc header files in `bazel-bin/tensorflow/`.

Comment: That sounds really useful - why is there no advice to do this in the official tensorflow docs (at least none I could find...)

Comment: @omatai if it helps remember to upvote my answer =x=x=x=x (shamelessly asking for upvote). i think is because official doc do not support c++ build by default.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, there is no official distributable C++ API package. There is, however, [tensorflow_cc](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc) project that builds and installs TF C++ API for you, along with convenient CMake targets you can link against.

Although it probably installs slightly more files than necessary, you can find the list of installed headers in [CMakeLists.txt:130](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc/blob/master/tensorflow_cc/CMakeLists.txt#L130):

```
# install *all* files with .h extension
/tensorflow/**/*.h
# install all dependencies downloaded by contrib/makefile
/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/
# install all files from third_party folder (e.g., Eigen/Tensor)
/tensorflow/third_party/
```

And you can find the list of directories which should be included by your compiler in [CMakeLists.txt:58](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc/blob/master/tensorflow_cc/CMakeLists.txt#L58):

```
/tensorflow
/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles
/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads
/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen
/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/gemmlowp
/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf-host/include
```

Note that C++ API requires also eigen and protobuf headers and libraries, which are, in case of tensorflow_cc, built using [contrib/makefile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile) from TF repo.

You may prefer to use [tensorflow_cc](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc) directly so that you don't have to bother with all this manually.

Answer (score -2):

An alternative way to build `libtensorflow_cc.so` is to use `tensorflow/tensorflow:devel-gpu` docker image, then build it with command:

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
```